# how do i host .onion on my top level domain name

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-routing, torsocks

I understand how to start up a TLD and host the website.
how do i host .onion on my top level domain name. Do we purchase the .onion?
Any suggestions on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you get a randomized name assigned to you. Don't think you can reserve a specific name. General instructions for setting up an onion site can be found here:
https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-onion-service.html